# App Inventor: How to remove empty items from list?

Tags: android, list, app-inventor

How could I remove all empty or whitespace-only items from an **App Inventor** list? I have not been able to find anything that works. Either an extension or an App Inventor function would be fine.

Comment: Could you please specify object type of the list.

Comment: can you please add your code?

Comment: @MohammadMisbah It is a list of strings.

Comment: @AkshathaSrinivas I didn't have any.

Comment: No need for more answers, I found an extension.

Comment: share your answer, so that it help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an extension called `ListUtils` that was exactly what I needed. It also has a bunch of other features. Please see the link for more info. https://amerkashi.wordpress.com/2017/03/05/shuffling-ordering-lists/

Answer (score 0):

create your own custom procedure like this:
use a `for each in list` loop starting from the end (i.e. length of list) decrementing by -1
inside the loop check each item, if it is an empty string, if yes, remove that item from the list

you might want to try something and if you got stuck, edit your question and post a screenshot of what you have tried...

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Object obj : list){
   if(obj.isEmpty()){              // add other conditions if you have
      list.remove(obj);
   }
}
```

Replace the `Object` with your list object type. Ex: if it is `String`, replace `Object` with `String` in the for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please use some of the below-mentioned methods:-

Normlly `arrayList.removeIf(item -> item == null || "".equals(item));`

With Guava you can do `arrayList.removeIf(Strings::isNullOrEmpty);`

With Apache Commons `arrayList.removeIf(StringUtils::isEmpty);`

Finally, you can try below one:-

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("", "Hi", null, "How"));
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
```